# How get ACF of category on WP-Rest?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How can I get an ACF field on category endpoint?
Only find for posts, but **category**...

My functions.php:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_fields' );

register_rest_field(
        'category', 
        'avatar', //New Field Name in JSON RESPONSEs
        array(
            'get_callback' => function() {return get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'avatar', true);}          
        ));
```

On WP:

[image: Wordpress ACF]

Comment: Did you use this plugin to get the acf fields in rest? https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/

Comment: @rank  Thank you very much! U saved me!